# Whose bug is this - clang or gcc?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, standards

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool IsMatched()
{
    string str = R"(Liy_0-3863)";
    string re = R"([:\-_a-zA-Z\d]+)";

    auto flags = std::regex_constants::ECMAScript;
    return std::regex_match(str.data(),
        std::regex(re.data(), re.size(), flags));
}

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha << IsMatched();
}
```

- **clang 4.0** outputs `true`;
- **gcc 6.2** outputs `false`.

**Whose bug is this - clang or gcc?**

Comment: GCC trunk prints `true`, so I think the answer is obvious.

Comment: The question title is very misleading. This question can never be found by searching. Please make the title more descriptive of the issue and add regex to the keywords.

Comment: @Ryan it's this one \-

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77469

Answer (score 4, accepted):

g++ (or rather stdlibc++) is in the error.

According to the ECMAScript specification, an escaped minus character should be treated literally within a character class. libstdc++ fails to do so. It can be seeon on a simpler example

```
   string: a-b
   regex: [a\-b]+
```

gcc says there's no match, various regex testers say there is.